# Exporting completed webiste for another server

Tags: mysql, import, server, export

I've been working on a Wordpress website with WooCommerce etc for my friends business for a while. It's pretty much done, all products are added etc.

However this has been done on my own webhost / server since my friend's business was already running so I couldn't create the site on his server since he has customers everyday.

So now my question is, how do I upload the completed website to his server? I tried just copying all files etc but then I run in to problems with the mysql etc.

So basically how do I export the website and upload it on another server.

Comment: Is your friends website currently using wordpress? Is so, use wordpress' buildin import and export function

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult.

You need to transfer files to the new server. Create a blank database and keep it's name, user_name (this user must have all privileges of this newly created database) and password.

Edit config.php file on new server with the these new details.

Read: [Wordpress Codex for transferring site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that all the configuration in the `wp-config.php` file is still relevant to your production environment (check database host, and password, and db name).

Secondly, you might want to change the absolute URLs in your database with your production URLs. The main things you will want to change are in the `wp_options` table: `siteurl` and `home`.

Of course, if you uploaded a lot of data in your local Wordpress database, you might just want to do a search and replace for all the absolute URLs to your new environment (helpful if you uploaded media and such).